# Remove duplicated subsets from very large table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The data I'm working with is fairly complicated, so I'm just going to provide a simpler example so I can hopefully expand that out to what I'm working on.

Note: I've already found a way to do it, but it's extremely slow and not scalable. It works great on small datasets, but if I applied it to the actual tables it needs to run on, it would take forever.

I need to remove entire duplicate subsets of data within a table. Removing duplicate rows is easy, but I'm stuck finding an efficient way to remove duplicate subsets.

Example:

```
GroupID  Subset Value
-------  ----   ----
1        a      1
1        a      2
1        a      3

1        b      1
1        b      3
1        b      5

1        c      1
1        c      3
1        c      5


2        a      1
2        a      2
2        a      3

2        b      4
2        b      5
2        b      6

2        c      1
2        c      3
2        c      6
```

So in this example, from GroupID 1, I would need to remove either subset 'b' or subset 'c', doesn't matter which since both contain Values 1,2,3. For GroupID 2, none of the sets are duplicated, so none are removed.

Here's the code I used to solve this on a small scale. It works great, but when applied to 10+ Million records...you can imagine it would be very slow (I was later informed of the number of records, the sample data I was given was much smaller)...:

```
DECLARE @values TABLE (GroupID INT NOT NULL, SubSet VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, [Value] INT NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @values (GroupID, SubSet, [Value])
VALUES  (1,'a',1),(1,'a',2),(1,'a',3)  ,(1,'b',1),(1,'b',3),(1,'b',5)  ,(1,'c',1),(1,'c',3),(1,'c',5),
        (2,'a',1),(2,'a',2),(2,'a',3)  ,(2,'b',2),(2,'b',4),(2,'b',6)  ,(2,'c',1),(2,'c',3),(2,'c',6)

SELECT *
FROM @values v
ORDER BY v.GroupID, v.SubSet, v.[Value]

SELECT x.GroupID, x.NameValues, MIN(x.SubSet)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.GroupID, t1.SubSet
        , NameValues = (SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), t2.[Value]) FROM @values t2 WHERE t1.GroupID = t2.GroupID AND t1.SubSet = t2.SubSet ORDER BY t2.[Value] FOR XML PATH(''))
    FROM @values t1
    GROUP BY t1.GroupID, t1.SubSet
) x
GROUP BY x.GroupID, x.NameValues
```

All I'm doing here is grouping by GroupID and Subset and concatenating all of the values into a comma delimited string...and then taking that and grouping on GroupID and Value list, and taking the MIN subset.

Comment: Hi have tou try to perform this query at same but with the use off cte ? Just for comparative performance propose.

Comment: @pascalsanchez no I haven't, but I'll give it a try. I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this with a recursive CTE, but I don't think that would be any more efficient with a large table.

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like this:

```
;with cte as
(
    select v.GroupID, v.SubSet, checksum_agg(v.Value) h, avg(v.Value) a
    from @values v
    group by v.GroupID, v.SubSet
)

delete v
from @values v
join
(
    select c1.GroupID, case when c1.SubSet > c2.SubSet then c1.SubSet else c2.SubSet end SubSet
    from cte c1
    join cte c2 on c1.GroupID = c2.GroupID and c1.SubSet <> c2.SubSet and c1.h = c2.h and c1.a = c2.a
)x on v.GroupID = x.GroupID and v.SubSet = x.SubSet

select *
from @values
```

Comment: Nice, passes the first test, gives me the results I was looking for. I'll test it out on the full dataset and see how it performs on 10M+ records.

Comment: Just ran it on the larger dataset, certainly runs faster than my original code. Thanks!

Comment: @chadwin, cool. I've updated the query, you can try the new version, possibly it can be slightly faster.

Comment: So I dove a little deeper into this. It seems using CHECKSUM_AGG and AVG still produce some false matches, but a very low percentage. However, I've expanded on your method, and have included other aggregate fields like SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX etc. It seems CHECKSUM_AGG, AVG, COUNT, SUM is the only one so far to produce a perfect match to my original code. But I'm testing other combinations of aggregate functions to see which perform better but still produce the same results.

Comment: In case you were interested...I ran a test on all 64 possible combinations of using CHECKSUM_AGG, AVG, COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX...the only combinations of two aggregate functions that produced zero false matches were SUM & (MIN or MAX) ||| CHECKSUM_AGG & SUM.

Comment: @chadwin, I believe this depends on the distribution of the values. Glad you found the best approach in your case.

Answer (score 2):

From [`Checksum_Agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> The CHECKSUM_AGG result does not depend on the order of the rows in
>   the table.

This is because it is a sum of the values: `1 + 2 + 3 = 3 + 2 + 1 = 3 + 3 = 6`.

[`HashBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is designed to produce a different value for two inputs that differ only in the order of the bytes, as well as other differences. (There is a small possibility that two inputs, perhaps of wildly different lengths, could hash to the same value. You can't take an arbitrary input and squeeze it down to an absolutely unique 16-byte value.)

The following code demonstrates how to use `HashBytes` to return for each `GroupId`/`Subset`.

```
-- Thanks for the sample data!
DECLARE @values TABLE (GroupID INT NOT NULL, SubSet VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL, [Value] INT NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO @values (GroupID, SubSet, [Value])
VALUES  (1,'a',1),(1,'a',2),(1,'a',3)  ,(1,'b',1),(1,'b',3),(1,'b',5)  ,(1,'c',1),(1,'c',3),(1,'c',5),
        (2,'a',1),(2,'a',2),(2,'a',3)  ,(2,'b',2),(2,'b',4),(2,'b',6)  ,(2,'c',1),(2,'c',3),(2,'c',6);

SELECT *
FROM @values v
ORDER BY v.GroupID, v.SubSet, v.[Value];

with
  DistinctGroups as (
    select distinct GroupId, Subset
      from @Values ),
  GroupConcatenatedValues as (
    select GroupId, Subset, Convert( VarBinary(256), (
      select Convert( VarChar(8000), Cast( Value as Binary(4) ), 2 ) AS [text()]
        from @Values as V
        where V.GroupId = DG.GroupId and V.SubSet = DG.SubSet
        order by Value
        for XML Path('') ), 2 ) as GroupedBinary
     from DistinctGroups as DG )
  -- To see the intermediate results from the CTE you can use one of the
  --   following two queries instead of the last   select :
  --   select * from DistinctGroups;
  --   select * from GroupConcatenatedValues;
  select GroupId, Subset, GroupedBinary, HashBytes( 'MD4', GroupedBinary ) as Hash
    from GroupConcatenatedValues
    order by GroupId, Subset;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use checksum_agg() over a set of rows.  If the checksums are the same, this is strong evidence that the 'values' columns are equal within the grouped fields.

In the 'getChecksums' cte below, I group by the group and subset, with a checksum based on your 'value' column.

In the 'maybeBadSubsets' cte, I put a row_number over each aggregation just to identify the 2nd+ row in the event the checksums match.

Finally, I delete any subgroups so identified.

```
with

    getChecksums as (

        select      groupId,
                    subset,
                    cs = checksum_agg(value)
        from        @values v
        group by    groupId,
                    subset 

    ),

    maybeBadSubsets as (

        select      groupId,
                    subset,
                    cs,

                    deleteSubset = 
                        case 
                        when    row_number() over (
                                    partition by groupId, cs 
                                    order by subset
                                ) > 1 
                        then 1
                        end

        from        getChecksums

    )

    delete      v 
    from        @values v
    where       exists (
                    select  0
                    from    maybeBadSubsets mbs
                    where   v.groupId = mbs.groupId
                    and     v.SubSet = mbs.subset
                    and     mbs.deleteSubset = 1
            );
```

I don't know what the exact likelihood is for checksums to match.  If you're not comfortable with the false positive rate,  you can still use it to eliminate some branches in a more algorithmic approach in order to vastly improve performance.

Note: CTE's can have a quirk performance-wise.  If you find that the query engine is running 'maybeBadSubsets' for each row of @values, you may need to put its results into a temp table or table variable before using it.  But I believe with 'exists' you're okay as far at that goes.

**EDIT:**

I didn't catch it, but as the OP noticed, checksum_agg seems to perform very poorly in terms of false hits/misses.  I suspect it might be due to the simplicity of the input.  I changed

```
cs = checksum_agg(value)
```

above to

```
cs = checksum_agg(convert(int,hashbytes('md5', convert(char(1),value))))
```

and got better results.  But I don't know how it would perform on larger datasets.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this out and see how it performs. For my specific use, it doesn't need to be perfect, we're just trying to reduce the data. If there's still some dups left over it will probably be fine. I actually thought of using checksum, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work, I had completely forgotten about the aggregate function for it.

Comment: Hmm, it does look like there may be a bug in this, as it removed subset 'b' from GroupID 2, when it shouldn't have. I'll try and figure out why.

Comment: Ahh, okay, figured it out, looks like not only will CHECKSUM_AGG produce false negatives, but I didn't think about false positives. It deleted subsets with matching check sum values but weren't actually equivalent subsets.

Comment: Hey, I imagine by now you're going to utilize the cte approach by Kirill.  However, could you give the above mentioned change in the edit a try just to satisfy my curiosity?

Comment: will do! I'll be back in the office on Friday, sorry I'll have to keep you in suspense. Lol

Comment: When comparing checksums there's always a risk that 2 checksums for different data are exactly same. And this is not just related to SQL. That's why it's safer to also compare it with something extra, like a total or average of the data. Just to lower the odds of a false-positive. (personally I think comparing it to a [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) would be safer, but that would require MS Sql Server 2017 or higher)

Comment: So basically, a checksum compare can prove 100% that data is different if the checksums are different. But it doesn't prove 100% that the data is the same if the checksums are the same.

Comment: @LukStorms, I get that, I was just not prepared that the likelihood of a match was so strong.  I was wondering if it had to do with the very small and simple inputs (1,2,3), (1,3,5), and so on.  So I wanted to know if the aggregated checksum against an integer from a hashed value would throw in enough wrenches for the agg function to give far fewer undesired matches.

Comment: Looks like it does produce the correct results on the sample dataset I provided. I will apply this to the larger dataset to see how it performs and if it gives me the correct results. One thing I'd like to note, that I discovered this morning with Kirill's method, is that it still produces false matches, but a very low percent. So I'm working on using other combinations of aggregate functions to remove the false matches.